# How does InnoDB compute table_rows for information_schema?

Tags: mysql, innodb, information-schema

## Background

So, I understand that for InnoDB tables, `table_rows` from `information_schema` is "only a rough estimate", and that counting the exact number of rows is nontrivial because of transactions.

But I have some tables for which `table_rows` is within a few % of the true count, and some tables like this:

```
mysql> SELECT table_rows FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name="__unit_previews";
+------------+
| table_rows |
+------------+
|  226992266 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM __unit_previews;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   144156 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.14 sec)
```

I think you'd have to be pretty generous to call this a "rough estimate".

There are no open transactions; I didn't secretly delete a few hundred million rows; I ran `analyze table` to make sure the information schema was up-to-date.

I'm running MySQL 5.6.13 (`@@innodb_version` also says 5.6.13) and this table has `row_format=dynamic` with about 400kB of blob attributes per row. `information_schema` also reports that `data_length` is 58020446208 and `avg_row_length` is 255.

## Questions

So how does InnoDB calculate `table_rows` for `information_schema.tables`?

Possibly related: how does it determine `data_length` and `avg_row_length`? Does this include "external" blob storage (i.e. off the B-tree page but still managed by InnoDB)?

If `table_rows` is being used in SQL optimization, should I be worried that it's off by 3 orders of magnitude?

Is there a better way to estimate the number of rows from the attributes available in `information_schema`?

Comment: Disclaimer: I have no clue how to answer your questions, but I know one thing - you can't rely on information_schema for data size or number of rows. Ever. I use a simple trigger that increments/decrements a counter for a specific table whose row count I have to know. Apart from that approach, I haven't found anything better. As for size of the data, the amount allocated and spent are never the same. Thus, I simply ask my OS to tell me the size on disk. It doesn't answer your questions sadly, but until someone more knowledgeable jumps in.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `DELETE` you did has an impact.

InnoDB knows exactly what the value of `Data_length`.  From probes (8 in old versions), it has some feel (granted, a very poor feel) for the distribution of stuff.  I *think* it gets an estimate of `Avg_row_length`, then divides to get `table_rows`.

Run `ANALYZE` again; the first number will stay the same; the other two will change.

`TEXT` and `BLOB` fields (etc) are stored into an off-block storage in different ways, depending on `ROW_FORMAT`.  This adds to the confusion and calculations.

Newer versions (since 5.6.6?) do a slightly better job.

Being off by a factor of 1000 is really bad.  I rarely see more than a factor of 2 (either direction).

I just tried one of my tables similar to yours, and got a factor of 7.  Hehe - `ANALYZE` made the row count farther from the truth.  `OPTIMIZE` made it better, but still off by 5x.  Oh, well.

Suggest you post a bug on http://bugs.mysql.com.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding--I was trying to say that I did not do a `DELETE` (in fact this table is almost never deleted or updated). I suspect you're right that it divides `data_length` by `avg_row_length`, and that the problem arises from how off-block storage is counted--it seems to be included in `data_length` but not included in the estimate of `avg_row_length`. I'll see about posting a bug report.